# Using sample at lower hierarchical level (products) to draw inferences about a higher hierarchical level (companies)

Tags: inference, multilevel-analysis, sample

I have a conceptual question about whether we can use a random sample of *products* to draw inferences about *companies*. More generally, I think this would extend to sampling hierarchical data, where we want to do inference at a different level from where the sample is drawn.

Here's the basic setup: there are $i=\{1, ..., M\}$ companies. Each company $i$ sells a set of products $X_{ij}$ where $j=\{1,...,N_i\}$, such that $N_i$ is the total number of products the $i^\text{th}$ company sells. Each product $X_{ij}$ either contains a warning label or it doesn't. Using a website, we can do a search query and get a listing (i.e., sample frame) of all $\sum_i N_i$ products. We draw a random sample of those products and record each product's company and whether the product contains a warning label or not. The goal is to use this random sample to estimate the total number of unique companies that sell at least one product with a warning label.

We can assume the distribution of $N_i$ is known. An example would be $N_i \sim \text{NegBin}\left(\text{size}=1, \text{prob}=\frac{1}{6}\right) + 1$, but I'm hoping to understand how to apply the solution for any known distribution. (This might be a sloppy way of writing the distribution--I'm adding 1 so that the total number of products per company is never 0.)

Let's say we found there are 52,000 total products based on the search results. We sampled 500 products and found that there are 480 unique parent companies. As a simple case, let's say 100% of products have warning labels. I know it would be incorrect to think that there are $\frac{480}{500}\times 52,000 = 49,920$ unique companies with at least one product that has a warning label, because companies with more products are more likely to show up in the sample.

But what's the correct way to get from the sample of products to an estimate of the total number of companies?

I tried to create some simulations, but I'm still not getting very far / haven't figured out what to do with the simulated data.

```r
library(tidyverse)

N_comps <- 10000 # number of companies
set.seed(1356)
n_prod <- 1 + rnbinom(N_comps, size=1, prob=1/6) 
    # total number of products for each company
compID <- 1:N_comps # give each company an ID
comp.df <- data.frame(compID, n_prod) # store in dataframe
N_prod <- sum(comp.df$n_prod) # total number of products

prodID <- unlist(map(comp.df$n_prod, ~1:.x)) # give each product an ID
compID <- unlist(map2(comp.df$compID, comp.df$n_prod, ~rep(.x, .y))) 
# repeat company IDs for each associated product
prod.df <- data.frame(prodID, compID)
prod.df$hasLabel <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), N_prod, replace=TRUE, 
    prob=c(1.00, 0)) # assume they all have labels for simplicity
sampSize <- seq(100, nrow(prod.df), 400) 
    # gradually the increase the product sample size
results <- rep(NA, length(sampSize)) # vector to store the results

set.seed(21551)
for(i in 1:length(sampSize)){
  prodSamp <- sample(1:nrow(prod.df), size=sampSize[i]) 
    # draw the sample of products
  results[i] <- prod.df %>% 
                  slice(prodSamp) %>% 
                  filter(hasLabel) %>% 
                  distinct(compID) %>% 
                  nrow() # count number of distinct companies
}
```